# Why does GCE Load Balancer behave differently through the domain name and the IP address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, health-monitoring

A backend service happens to be returning Status 404 on the health check path of the Load Balancer. When I browse to the Load Balancer's domain name, I get "Error: Server Error/ The server encountered a temporary error", and the logs show

`"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.loadbalancing.type.LoadBalancerLogEntry" 
  statusDetails: "failed_to_pick_backend"`, which makes sense.

When I browse to the Load Balancer's Static IP, my browser shows the 404 Error Message which the underlying Kubernetes Pod returned, In other words   the Load Balancer passed on the request despite the failed health check.

Why these two different behaviors?

[Edit]

Here is the yaml for the Ingress that created the Load Balancer:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: if you have a kubernetes deployment that you would to expose to internet, it can be useful if you show us the used procedure

Comment: If it were me, I'd take a dump of the contents of BOTH request contents.  From a caller's perspective, the caller resolves the DNS name and sends the request to the IP so what we are looking for is what is the distinction between the two calls.  Maybe path or maybe some HTTP header.  If we can find the distinction, we will be closer to finding the explanation.

Comment: An HTTP GET request to the IP address of a Google load balancer will return 404 if your request is missing a recognized HTTP HOST header.

Comment: When the service is healthy, does a request made with the IP behave the same as those using the hostname?

Comment: @michael, I don't know, as this is a particular system that we're debugging. However, for other systems, we do the the same behavior for access to IP address or DNS name

Comment: @JohnHanley Could you point me to documentation on the "a recognized HTTP HOST". In my case,   requests to either the DNS name or IP address  return 404, which I think originates in the underlying app.

Comment: @c4f4t0r What do you mean by "used procedure" . There is a Deployment, exposed as NodePort, with an Ingress exposing that NodePort.

Comment: I do not know of a document but there probably is one. My knowledge comes from working with the service and debugging many issues. Today, most proxy/load balancers require the HTTP Host header. That is how they know which backend to pass the request to.

Comment: @JohnHanley  In the simple cases, like this one, the LB just has to choose one of a number of identical servers the backend, so it doesn't need to choose a host/domain. Also, this says "A default service is defined to handle any requests that do not match a specified host rule" https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/#url_maps

Comment: could you share LB config yaml and shed some light on how you query it for a Healthcheck? I'd like to mimic setup and play with it.

Comment: @Nick I added it.

Comment: In my comment I mentioned "recognized HTTP Host header". At that time you question has very little details on how you have everything configured. My comments are just tips to help you.

Comment: Is it a GKE cluster, or a managed one?

Comment: It is a  GKE cluster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a "deep dive" into that and managed to reproduce the situation on my GKE cluster, so now I can tell that there are a few things combined here.

> A backend service happens to be returning Status 404 on the health check path of the Load Balancer.

There could be 2 options (it is not clear from the description you have provided).

- something like: 
  "**Error: Server Error** 
  The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
  Please try again in 30 seconds."

This one you are geting from LoadBalancer in case HealthCheck failed for pod. The official [documentation on GKE Ingress object](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) says that

> a Service exposed through an Ingress must respond to health checks from the load balancer.
>
> Any container that is the final destination of load-balanced traffic must do one of the following to indicate that it is healthy:
>
> - Serve a response with an HTTP 200 status to GET requests on the  `/`  path.
> - Configure an  [HTTP readiness probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-readiness-probes). Serve a response with an HTTP 200 status to GET requests on the  `path`  specified by the readiness probe. The Service exposed through an Ingress must point to the same container port on which the readiness probe is enabled.

It is needed to fix HealthCheck handling. You can check Load balancer details by visiting GCP console - Network Services - Load Balancing.

- "**404 Not Found** -- nginx/1.17.6"

This one is clear. That is the response returned by  endpoint `myservice` is sending request to. It looks like something is misconfigured there.  My guess is that pod merely can't serve that request properly. Can be nginx web-server issue, etc. Please check the configuration to find out why pod can't serve the request.

While playing with the setup I have find an [image](https://github.com/mendhak/docker-http-https-echo) that allows you to check if request has reached the pod and requests headers.

so it is possible to create a pod like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  annotations:
    run: fake-web
  name: fake-default-knp
#  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  containers:
  - image: mendhak/http-https-echo
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: fake-web
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
```

to be able to see all the headers that were in incoming requests (`kubectl logs -f fake-default-knp` ).

> When I browse to the Load Balancer's Static IP, my browser shows the 404 Error Message which the underlying Kubernetes Pod returned.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myservice
          servicePort: 80
```

Upon creation of such an Ingress object, there will be at least 2 backends in GKE cluster. 
- the backend you have specified upon Ingress creation ( `myservice` one)
- the default one (created upon cluster creation).

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o wide
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP       
l7-default-backend-xyz     1/1     Running   0          20d   10.52.0.7
```

Please note that `myservice` serves **only** requests that have `Host` header set to `example.com` . The rest of requests are sent to "default backend" .  That is the reason why you are receiving "default backend - 404" error message upon browsing to LoadBalancer's IP address.

Technically there is a `default-http-backend` service that has `l7-default-backend-xyz` as an EndPoint.

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system -o wide 
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE   SELECTOR
default-http-backend   NodePort    10.0.6.134    <none>        80:31806/TCP    20d   k8s-app=glbc

kubectl get ep -n kube-system
NAME                   ENDPOINTS       AGE
default-http-backend   10.52.0.7:8080  20d
```

Again, that's the "object" that returns the "default backend - 404" error for the requests with "Host" header not equal to the one you specified in Ingress.

Hope that it sheds a light on the issue :)

EDIT:

> myservice serves only requests that have Host header set to example.com." So you are saying that requests go to the LB only when there is a host header?

Not exactly. The LB receives all the requests and passes requests in accordance to "Host" header value. Requests with `example.com` Host header are going to be served on `myservice` backend .

To put it simple the logic is like the following:

1. request arrives;
2. system checks the Host header (to determine user's backend)
3. request is served if there is a suitable user's backend ( according to the Ingress config) and that backend is healthy , otherwise "**Error: Server Error** The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds." is thrown if backend is in non-healthy state;
4. if request's `Host` header doesn't match any host in Ingress spec, request is sent to `l7-default-backend-xyz` backend (not the one that is mentioned in Ingress config). That backend replies with: "default backend - 404" error .

Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed investigation. The 404 that we see when accessing over the IP address is  expected--there is nothing available at that path so 404 is the right thing, But why do we see a LB error over the domain name? Your answer  is "myservice serves only requests that have Host header set to example.com." So you are saying that requests go to the LB only when there is a  host header? OK, so why the LB error in that case?

Comment: @JoshuaFox , sorry I've been sick (no access to Internet :) ). I've edited my answer.