# Is it possible to create a GKE Ingress without a default backend?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

The Ingress [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend) states that:

> An Ingress with no rules sends all traffic to a single default
>   backend. The default backend is typically a configuration option of
>   the Ingress controller and is not specified in your Ingress resources.
>
> If none of the hosts or paths match the HTTP request in the Ingress
>   objects, the traffic is routed to your default backend.

All GKE Ingress objects I manage point to a specific backend like:

```
spec:
  rules:
    - host: my.host.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: the service
              servicePort: 1337
```

Is there anyway to create these Ingress objects without the default backend?
If so, what are the consequences of this?

Comment: I've been playing with the default backend. Can I ask you to share more info on why do you need creating such an ingress? :)

Comment: Well, I just don't need it. Currently, I don't care about requests that aren't being captured by the Ingress configuration

Comment: Ok. I'll provide that info as an general answer then :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there anyway to create these Ingress objects without the default backend? If so, what are the consequences of this?

Short answer is: **No**, you can't create Ingress without having the "default backend" as a last resort. The default backend is a part of default behaviour of kubernetes.

That behaviour is explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553702/why-does-gce-load-balancer-behave-differently-through-the-domain-name-and-the-ip/59666174#59666174).

All the requests that have no matching backend in your Ingress definition will be forwarded to the "default backend" ("request - response" logic, no orphaned requests).

As we can see from: `cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc/default-svc-controller.yaml`

says that:

```
    # Any image is permissible as long as:
    # 1. It serves a 404 page at /
    # 2. It serves 200 on a /healthz endpoint
    image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-gce-404-server-with-metrics-amd64:v1.6.0
```

That is why you can put your own custom image for the `kube-system/l7-default-backend` deployment.

You can find additional details in:

- cluster/gce/manifests/glbc.manifest
- cluster/addons/cluster-loadbalancing/glbc/default-svc.yaml

files.

Hope that info sheds some light on why there is a `default backend` and how it works.