# k3s ingress "default-http-backend" not found

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, k3s

TL;DR:  Setup a service with the same name as the deployment and ingress ports all match still getting:

```
error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found
```

Here is Service yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1

kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sonarr
  namespace: media
spec:
  selector:
    app: sonarr
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8989
    targetPort: 80
```

kubectl apply -f svc.yaml results

```sh
 kubectl describe svc sonarr -n media
Name:              sonarr
Namespace:         media
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=sonarr
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.43.184.97
IPs:               10.43.184.97
Port:              <unset>  8989/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.42.1.10:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Deployment Yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarr
  namespace: media
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonarr
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarr
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sonarr
        image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/sonarr:arm32v7-latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8989
```

Deployment Results

```sh
kubectl get deployments -n media
NAME     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
sonarr   1/1     1            1           37m
```

Ingress yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sonarr-ingress
  namespace: media
  labels:
    name: sonarr-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: sonarr.smrtrock.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: sonarr
            port: 
              number: 8989
```

Ingress description

```sh
kubectl describe ing sonarr -n media
Name:             sonarr
Namespace:        media
Address:
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host                 Path  Backends
  ----                 ----  --------
  sonarr.smrtrock.com
                       /   sonarr:8989 (10.42.1.10:80)
Annotations:           <none>
Events:                <none>
```

Not sure what I am missing pretty new to k8s.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. [default-http-backend](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#default-backend) is a place where all your  request go if they **DO NOT** match any of your ingress rules. Most probably there was no this recourse
in your nginx installation yamls for your exact version.

> An Ingress with no rules sends all traffic to a single default
> backend. The defaultBackend is conventionally a configuration option
> of the Ingress controller and is not specified in your Ingress
> resources.
>
> If none of the hosts or paths match the HTTP request in the Ingress
> objects, the traffic is routed to your default backend.

Might be interesting to check:

- [default backend - 404 on GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61276085/9929015)
- [endpoints “default-http-backend” not found in Ingress resource](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67347050/9929015)

Comment: Can we configure our own service as the default backend? For example to route it to a default application like a custom NGINX.